# Ubuntu Kylin Software Center in English

Tags: software-center, kylin

I installed Ubuntu Kylin, but the Software Center is in the Chinese language.  How can I get it to be in English?

Comment: Ubuntu Kylin is for Chinese users as it conforms with government restrictions, you wouldn't expect it to be in English.

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu Kylin Software Center is strictly in Chinese. I tried several ways of changing this, some of which were:

- Removing the Chinese Language Support (No luck, you can't remove it from Kylin just in case)
- Installing English and setting it as default
- Installing English Language Pack through the terminal and doing locale update additionally to checking language support with `check-language-support`. Including rebooting just in case. No luck

My recommendation is to literally use the Software Center. If you go to the terminal you will notice you have 2 Software Centers. The Kylin Chinese only `ubuntu-kylin-software-center` and the normal Ubuntu Software Center `ubuntu-software`.

[image]

So simply either open the Dash, look for Software Center and drag it to the main menu in Kylin or run it from the terminal.